# How to disable "Multiple methods named ... found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes"

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, zxing, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I just started Xcode 6.3 with a project that I have been working on for a while. I did some changes and than ran the previously working program. Result: a build failure with the message

Compile ZXParsedResult.m...
[image]

So the ZXing library can suddenly not be compiled any more. I guess this is another XCode bug (the program will not run even after a reset of all changes to the previously working code base). Is it possible to disable this error message?

I already triggered a successful clean on the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like problem has been solved in latest version of library, see discussion on this issue https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/issues/208

If you are not ready to upgrade to latest version, I'd prefer this fix from discussion

- (id)parsedResultWithType:(ZXParsedResultType)type {
  return [(ZXParsedResult *)[self alloc] initWithType:type];
  }

More on such kind of errors
[new in Xcode 6.3/iOS 8.3: using self alloc for convenience constructor causes build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563701/new-in-xcode-6-3-ios-8-3-using-self-alloc-for-convenience-constructor-causes-bu)